# Peers vs Members - Consul

Tags: api, consul, raft

> Peer set - The peer set is the set of all members participating in log replication. For Consul's purposes, all server nodes are in the peer set of the local datacenter.

~ Quote from Official docs

1. What is the difference between peers and members then?
2. Why do we have following two APIs then? (one is enough?)

   ```
     i. /status/peers  
    ii. /agent/members
   ```
3. Could you please shed light on the internal details?
4. Is there a possibility of inconsistency in results of above APIs?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/consensus.html

Comment: "Peer set - The peer set is the set of all members participating in log replication. For Consul's purposes, all server nodes are in the peer set of the local datacenter."

Comment: @Héctor, Does it mean that both of them should give same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a comparison of `/agent/members/`, `status/peers/` and `catalog/nodes`.

The possible difference in response is because each of the API end point get data from different sources.

1. `/catalog/nodes`: The request recieved by any agent is redirected to the leader, and leader provides the response **from catalog**.
2. `/agent/members/`: Agent receives the request and return member information obtained **from gossip**. This can be different from `catalog` end point (as obvious from log replication mechanism (Consul uses Raft Prorocol) ).
3. `/status/peers/` : This API return the nodes participating in *'log replication'*.
   Ideally, this should be same as `/catalog/node`. But if there is a partition in the cluster, it is possible that, until the cluster recover, all members are not taking part in log replication. In this case `/catalog/nodes/` and `/status/peers/` can give different results.

To understand this proper, you need to know the raft protocol properly. [Reference](http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/#replication).